# Display an Alert Dialog Box for custom time period in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my android app I want to display an Alert dialog box for a limited time period. Which means If user  doesn't reply to alert dialog box within limited time period , alert box must be  closed. I searched on the Internet about this but could not  find a way. Is anyone aware about  how to do this ?

Comment: Try the accepted answer in this [SO post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445745/android-close-dialog-after-5-seconds

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options spring to mind
You need to call the dialog dismiss() function right? so it's just a case of knowing when to call it.

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

The ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in the first link looks like just the ticket for you.

The accepted answer here [Where do I create and use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, TimerTask, or Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098806/where-do-i-create-and-use-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-timertask-or-handler) shows an example to how to use it. You would set it up in the onCreate of the Dialog class you are showing or at the time when you show the dialog in the calling class.

Answer (score 0):

#### you can do like this

```
private final Runnable mDismissAction = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        dismissDialog();
    }
};
```

then you can dissmiss the dialog delay, use

```
handler.postDelayed(mDismissAction, delay);
```

when user click the dialog it will cancel the action, use

```
handler.removeCallbacks(mDissmissAction)
```