# How to verify if the user has enterd any button on alert dialog box or not

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have alert dialog box having two button 
    a. OK
    b. No

If user press ok some operation is performed
     else some other action is performed .

What I am looking for is that to check if user has entered any button or not 
   if he has not, After few second I wish to send some message.
Would any one help me with this ??

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want to perform an action after a user has not done anything on the alert dialog right? Say he presses the back button

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Right now, your question is quite broad! Please have a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to see how you could improve your question!

Comment: @olucode: Yeah it is like server is expecting reply from client say Y/N , BUT AT THE SAME TIME CLIENT failed to respond , then I wish to send the message from client to server after few second .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) after your `AlertDialog.show()` method.

```
yourDialog.show();

final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (yourDialog.isShowing()) {
            // Send some message
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}, 2000); // Seconds in milliseconds
```

Also check this question for other possibilities:
[Android close dialog after 5 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445745/android-close-dialog-after-5-seconds)

Comment: thank for that reply, i didnt understand the use of ...........> if(dialog.isShowing()) .... but if am right is that condition is to ,check whether  user has entered button or not ???

Comment: The method `Dialog.isShowing()` just returns _whether the dialog is currently showing_. I assume that the dialog get close if one of the buttons got clicked.

Nice to hear, that you got it! :-)

Comment: is there any way to check if user has clicked  either YES or NO button. I want to SEND SOME MESSAGE only if there is no input from user (i.e if he hasn't entered yes or no then send some message)

Comment: You can set a boolean variable for example `isClicked` which you change to true in the `onClickListener` of the OK or NO action. Then you can check for the value in the timer. But don't you close the Dialog after the NO or OK action got clicked?

Comment: yes I do want to close it, but at same time I want to make sure that if user does not click any one of option then do send some message to server.    i.e if positive button = some action

Comment: i.e if positive button = some action   else = some other action . finally within timer see if user has entered yes or no if he hasn' t then send message to server or else just close dialog box !!!!!

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me, my question was if your Dialog get closed when you click on the Yes or No button? If so, there is no need to do it otherwise than in my answer above. :)